# Looking for an efficient snowflake SQL query for my problem

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Table1:

```
ID|Days between installments |Number_of_Payments|First_payment_date|Last_payment_date**
001| 7                       |5                 | 2022-01-01       | 2022-01-29
002| 7                       |2                 | 2022-10-01       | 2022-10-08
003| 5                       |3                 | 2022-05-01       | 2022-05-15
004| 3                       |1                 | 2022-11-01       | 2022-11-01
```

Table2:

```
ID |Payment_date|Payment_amount
001|2022-01-01  |100
001|2022-08-01  |50
001|2022-15-01  |20
001|2022-22-01  |50
001|2022-29-01  |20
002|2022-10-01  |500
002|2022-10-08  |400
003|2022-05-01  |350
003|2022-05-10  |250
003|2022-05-15  |200
004|2022-11-01  |900
```

My final table should look like:

```
ID|First_payment_date|First_Installment_date|First_Payment_date|First_Payment_Amount|Second_Installment_date|Second_Payment_date|Second_Payment_Amount|Third_Installment_date|third_Payment_date|Third_Payment_Amount|Fourth_Installment_date|Fourth_Payment_date|Fourth_Payment_Amount|Fifth_Installment_date|Fifth_Payment_date|Fifth_Payment_Amount|Last_payment_date**
001|2022-01-01|2022-01-01|100|2022-08-01|2022-08-01|50|2022-15-01|2022-15-01|20|2022-22-01|2022-22-01|50|2022-29-01|2022-29-01|20|2022-29-01
002|2022-10-01|2022-10-01|500|2022-10-08|2022-10-08|400|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|2022-10-08
003|2022-05-01|2022-05-01|350|2022-05-10|2022-05-10|250|2022-05-15|2022-05-15|200|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|2022-05-15
004|2022-11-01|2022-11-01|900||NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|2022-11-01
```

Could someone please let me know what is the best way to write this query. Thank you!

Comment: Snowflake is not MySQL or sql-server

Comment: I am looking for a sql solution, doesnt have to be platform specific.

Comment: "*doesnt have to be platform specific*" - Yea it does, because efficiency via code is going to be platform specific and ergo the code will vary. Each database system you tagged has different features and syntax (especially Snowflake being a different type of database system from the other two). What database system are you using?

Comment: I write my queries in the snowflake UI itself. Even if the query is not that efficient, can you help me with any SQL query, if the syntax is not compatible I can work on it to make it snowflake specific. Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: Indexes also matter... and you haven't shared any details of your schema, tables, etc.

Comment: Well both the tables are from different schemas, ID is the primary key and foreign key in both the tables. The tables should be joined based on ID and the dates. I'm sorry I am new to sql, can anyone help out.

Comment: @user2960654 I think the other comments have a problem because you added tags for `mysql` and `sql-server`. If this is a Snowflake problem, please remove the other tags. Or remove the Snowflake tag if this is not a Snowflake problem. If this is a general sql problem, then only keep the `sql` tag.

Answer (score 0):

### efficient

this means you have a method, so show it.

Also while we are anywhere near efficient, there is only efficiency inside a context, show/describe that.

While there are many great SQL coders on this site, reading the mind of people the cannot even be bother describing ANYTHING about their problem, is boring.